# How to import projects from SVN to Eclipse workspace with parent folders?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, code-composer

I installed Subversive SVN connectors to Code Composer Studio v6 (an Eclipse Based IDE for DSP Processors, everthing written is also valid for pure Eclipse). I imported a project with Import/Import/SVN -> Projects from SVN.

In SVN server I have the following structure:

---

- Trunk of the SVN Project
- Folder A

  - Folder B

    - **Project Folder**

      - Project file (.cproject, .project)
      - Project source files
- Folder C

  - **Some other source files**

---

So when I **import the Project**, the other source files under the **folder C** cannot be imported from the SVN server. They are listed under Project Properties -> Resource -> Linked Resources as a filepath

**PROJECT_LOC\..\..\..\Folder C** and sources could not be found.

When I import the "trunk" (The folder just above of Folder A and Folder C) I manage to import all files to workspace, but this time Eclipse does not see my project as a project so I cannot build any of my sources.

When I use TortoiseSVN, I import the complete filesystem, then import the project without from the Eclipse without checking "Copy files to workspace", I have no problem. But this time, I cannot perform SVN operations upon Eclipse.

How can I solve this issue? Is it impossible to import projects with parent folders?

Comment: No, projects must be in the workspace root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are for sure reasons for this project layout but it really isn't eclipse's preferred one. You should better create a project for the sources in folder C. Then you can check out both projects in a defined manner and add project C as a referenced project in project B.